# doctrine 2 duplicate entity when add with foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables in db : 'User' & 'Task'.
The task has a foreign key IdUser in cascade and this is the doctrine annotation on it :

```
/**
 * @var \MyBundle\Entity\User
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\MyBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"persist"})  
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idUser", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idUser;
```

My problem is when i try to create a new Task :
I set my task with my current user and then i persist & flush it. Everything goes fine exept that in database instead of linking this task to my current user, it duplicates my current user and link my Task to the new duplicated user.

Any idea how to avoid this ?

Comment: First, I would map the relation differently. Add property "tasks" to User and map it like OneToMany bidirectional relation.You should create new Task, add it to User (User should have addTask() method) and then you persist the User.

Comment: When working with bidirectional associations, make sure to add properties on both sides. For instance, User's addTask() method would look like this: public function addTask($task){ $task->setUser($this); $this->tasks[] = $task;}